# How to add the values for respective elements?

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have 3 XML structures as below:

```
a.xml
 <Books>
   <Book>
     <Publisher>ABC Pvt Ltd</Publisher>
     <Month>May</Month>
     <Year>2016</Year>
     <BooksReleased>4</BooksReleased>
   </Book>
 </Books>

b.xml
<Books>
   <Book>
     <Publisher>XYZ Pvt Ltd</Publisher>
     <Month>April</Month>
     <Year>2016</Year>
     <BooksReleased>2</BooksReleased>
   </Book>
 </Books>

c.xml
<Books>
   <Book>
     <Publisher>ABC Pvt Ltd</Publisher>
     <Month>June</Month>
     <Year>2016</Year>
     <BooksReleased>2</BooksReleased>
   </Book>
 </Books>
```

I would like to group these XML by publisher and also need to calculate its total no. of BooksReleased by the publisher for particular year.

required output format:

```
<TotalCalc>
  <PublishedBook>
    <Publisher>ABC Pvt Ltd</Publisher>
    <no.of books>6</no.of books>    
  </PublishedBook>
  <PublishedBook>
    <Publisher>XYZ Pvt Ltd</Publisher>
    <no.of books>2</no.of books>
  </PublishedBook>
</TotalCalc>
```

Kindly, help me i tried the following but its not working

```
typeswitch($Publisher)
case element (ABC Pvt Ltd)
  return sum($doc/BooksReleases[$doc/$Publisher = 'ABC Pvt Ltd'])
default return 'unknnown'
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to use [`cts:value-tuples`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-tuples) to pull up co-occurrences of `Publisher` and 'BooksReleased', which you can then iterate to aggregate by Publisher. That would scale much better. Something like:

```
let $aggregates := map:map()
let $_ :=
  for $tuple in cts:value-tuples((
    cts:element-reference(xs:QName("Publisher")),
    cts:element-reference(xs:QName("BooksReleased"))
  ))
  let $values := json:array-values($tuple)
  let $pub := $values[1]
  let $books as xs:int := $values[2]
  return map:put($aggregates, $pub, (map:get($aggregates, $pub), 0)[1] + $books)
return $aggregates
```

Note thought that this requires indexes on `Publisher` and `BooksReleased`, and it is important that each document contains only one (value of) `Publisher` to prevent cross-products.

I would also consider simply dropping (or ignoring) `BooksReleased`, and just making sure you save each book as a separate document. You can then use `cts:values` on `Publisher` and use `cts:frequency` on each publisher value to get the number of books for the publishers.

HTH!

Comment: is there any other possible way other than using tuples? as we are using version 7 tuples cannot be used

Comment: The function `cts:value-tuples` is known in MarkLogic 7 too: http://docs.marklogic.com/7.0/cts:value-tuples. In case you only need tuples of size two, you could also use the older [`cts:element-value-co-occurrences`](http://docs.marklogic.com/7.0/cts:element-value-co-occurrences) et al..

Comment: what will `cts:value-tuples` will return ? And why we are doing `json:array-values` over each item ?

Comment: Follow the link in my previous comment, or that at the top of my answer. cts:value-tuples returns `json:array*`. A json:array is a MarkLogic type that ensures order. XQuery sequences do that too, but cannot be nested. Json arrays can. Also, json arrays can have arbitrary length, which is useful since  cts:value-tuples allows one to pull up co-occurrence combinations of 2, but also combinations of 3, 4, or even more. See also the documentation of the function.